Nuxt v3 router is not working when trying to push or replace
I'm using Nuxt version 3.14 and whenever I try to use router.push or router.replace the tab freezes.
I tried all the possible fixes using setTimeout or debounce, but the only way I made it work was using window.location which is unfortunate because it refreshes the page.
Any ideas why does Nuxt have this bug or am I doing something wrong?

Depends on your code mostly.

its not an expected behavior of the nuxt router. there might a problem with
configurations in middleware or plugins. something like an infinite loop causing tab to freeze.

also nuxt router might freeze if you trigger a navigation to the same route with the same query parameters or path.
to better guide you, it’s better to see your code.

This is not an answer, hence should be posted as a comment.

I figure it out the bug was in the middleware indeed which caused the code to enter an infinite loop. So thank you!

@VisovanMihai glad it was helpful, your welcome.
